# How would ethereum migrate a whole transaction history after The Merge?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, security, ethereum-classic, the-merge

I have read press release of upcoming The Merge and face with promise to save a whole transaction history without tech details:

> No history is lost. As Mainnet gets merged with the Beacon Chain, it
> will also merge the entire transactional history of Ethereum. You
> don't need to do anything. Your funds are safe.

[(origin press-release)](https://ethereum.org/en/upgrades/merge/)

The question is how it will be done. In my understanding of ledger like systems adding a new transaction is based on previous transaction which means two things:

1. If you need to make a change in chain of transactions you have to recreate a whole chain since the beginning
2. Each transaction takes time to compute and this time growth with growth of total count of transactions

Therefore migrate a whole chain of transactions should take extreme amount of time\computational power they should not have.

Do you have any tech and concept details which could clarify this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No migration is needed because:

> the Merge is designed via a **block-inside-a-block structure**: the
> Ethereum PoW chain appears to continue, except past a certain
> transition point (i) the PoW nonces are no longer required to be
> valid, and (ii) the Ethereum PoW blocks, from then on referred to as
> execution blocks, are required to be embedded inside of beacon chain
> blocks.

[image]

Source: https://github.com/ethereum/annotated-spec/blob/master/merge/beacon-chain.md#introduction